# Converting SolidWorks STL files into urdf file

Tags: ros, urdf, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the solidworks stl file of my robot, but how can I convert it into urdf file? I have tried simmechanics_to_urdf, but it seems don't work at all. For example, the stl file is test.stl (asscii), which pkg and node can do this job. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36589/converting-solidworks-stl-files-into-urdf-file/) by [igoliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2527/igoliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-06-15**:
dornhenge is right that you can just use it in a URDF directly, but it won't have any flexible joints. What part of simmechanics_to_urdf were you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use an STL file directly as a mesh in a URDF [link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/link). There might be some issues when exporting the STL from SolidWorks. You need to choose the correct units and export as binary IIRC.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [igoliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2527/igoliao/) on 2012-06-15**:
Yeah, it really works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is now a solidworks plugin to do this. [sw_urdf_exporter](http://ros.org/wiki/sw_urdf_exporter)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-10-07**:
Outstanding thanks for the update